# reset p-table from ts page

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

i am using [Primeng table](https://primefaces.org/primeng/#/table) and after adding data to it, i want to reset the data- so it would show the new data. 
On the table, i am using "refresh" button, that call dt.reset()

### html

```
<p-table #dt [value]="pagedTasks">
..
<p-button icon="fa fa-refresh" iconPos="left" (click)="dt.reset()"></p-button>
```

if i clicked the button manually, the data get refreshed, i am trying to mimic the same functionality but from `ts` page.

### ts

```
..
import { TableModule } from 'primeng/table';
..
export class RenderQueueComponent implements OnInit {
     @ViewChild(TableModule) dt: TableModule;
     ..

  refresh() {
    this.dt.reset(); // property "reset" does not exist on type "TableModule"
  }
}
```

`refresh` **function** is getting called from other component, so the call is not shown here..

How can i achieve that?

Comment: not sure why, but i changed `import { TableModule } from 'primeng/table';` to `import { Table } from 'primeng/table';` and it started to work, why is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

not sure why, but i changed

```
import { TableModule } from 'primeng/table';
```

to:

```
import { Table } from 'primeng/table';
```

Table instead of TableModule

and it started to work, why is this?

Comment: Hey, my best guess is that TableModule (or any other Module) has to be set-up in app.module.ts but afterwards you just need the component, not a whole module as the object is that component.. ;)

Comment: TableModule is for the app.module.ts, you need to use the Table component throughout the app, its angular basics (or maybe not so basic).